# Reading the content of an XML file into an array/list

Tags: c#, xml

So I have an XML file that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Numbers>
    <int>3819</int>
    <int>2659</int>
    <int>2855</int>
    <int>8184</int>
    <int>5205</int>
    <int>9181</int>
    <int>4847</int>
    <int>582</int>
    <int>6928</int>
    <int>6390</int>
    <int>767</int>
    <int>9087</int>
    <int>8782</int>
    <int>7488</int>
    <int>5722</int>
    <int>4920</int>
  </Numbers>
</Data>
```

My goal is to read this XML file in C# and get the numbers in an array or a list like `int[] numbers` or `list<int> numbers`, numbers[0] = 3819, numbers[1] = 2659, ...

I have been looking around the internet on how to do so, but haven't seen any examples that would have the same form as this and I'd think if you have data like that, reading from a txt file would bee much easier, but now I have to specifically read this XML.

Comment: The term you're looking for is "deserialization". You need to *deserialize* the XML document.

Comment: `from num in XDocument.Load(@".\path\to\file.xml").Root.Descendants("int") select int.Parse(num.Value)`

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to use the [XDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/xdocument-class-overview) class.

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("filename");
XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
int[] numbers = doc
    .Descendants(ns + "int")
    .Select(x => int.Parse(x.Value))
    .ToArray();
```

While the namespace is [XNamespace.None](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnamespace.none) in the above, I've shown how you can prepend the namespace to the `int` element name. This will work regardless of whether the namespace is empty or not.

Also in the above, there is no error handling (e.g. what happens if `int` is not an integer).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
// Or XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("filename");

List<int> ints = doc.Descendants("int")
                    .Select(d => Convert.ToInt32(d.Value))
                    .ToList();
```